# I can't do a foreach of an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, foreach

So I was trying to make a for each of an object, but I can't do it and I really don't know why.

So I have this:

```
export class ProcessesModel {
  processName: string
  status: string
```

And I made variable out of this class as an array:

```
processStatus: ProcessesModel[] = [];
```

And I send values to the variable with a push, like so:

```
getProcessState(refDate: string) {

this.processStatus = new Array<ProcessesModel>();

for (const pClass of Array.from(this.processClasses.keys())) {
  this.dasboardService.getProcessSate(pClass, refDate)
  .then(
    (state) => {
      switch (state) {
        case 'Successful':
          this.processClasses.set(pClass, 'input successful');
          this.processStatus.push({processName: pClass, status: 'input successful'});
          break;
        case 'Executing':
          this.processClasses.set(pClass, 'input inprogress');
          this.processStatus.push({processName: pClass, status: 'input inprogress'});
          break;
        case 'Error':
          this.processClasses.set(pClass, 'input error');
          this.processStatus.push({processName: pClass, status: 'input error'});
          break;
        case 'Not Executed':
          this.processClasses.set(pClass, 'input');
          this.processStatus.push({processName: pClass, status: 'input'});
          break;
        default:
          this.processClasses.set(pClass, 'input');
          this.processStatus.push({processName: pClass, status: 'input'});
      }
    },
    (error) => {
      this.processClasses.set(pClass, 'input error');
      this.processStatus.push({processName: pClass, status: 'input error'});
    });

  }
```

Then I send this variable with an eventEmitter, and when I do a subscribe to that variable, it doesn't allow me to do a foreach loop. It doesn't do anything at all, not even an error.

When I print a normal object vs this one it print like so:

[image]

I can do a foreach out of the first object, but not with the second...

EDIT: When I receive all the data, I saved into a new variable:

```
processes: Array<any> = [];
```

And heres my subscribe:

```
this.captoolsComp.processes.subscribe((processes) => {
  this.processes = processes;

  processes.forEach(process => {
    this.setProcState(process.processName, process.status);
  });
```

Comment: can you post your service ?

Comment: Can you post the data you are trying to iterate over ( in text not image ) and the foreach function you wrote trying to iterate over that?

Answer (score 0):

my CONTENT is array and it has objects as

```
{ status: 1}
{ status: 0}
{ status: 1}
```

so i want to iterate each object and then i want to modify the element so it worked in this way

```
rowData : any;
x: any;
 this.rowData = response['CONTENT'];
             console.log( this.rowData);
             this.rowData.forEach( (element) => {
      this.x = element.status ;
             if ( this.x = 1) {

             element.status = 'Open';

                }
              else {
             element.status = 'Close';
               }

          });
          console.log( this.rowData);
```

so now i get the modified json in the final console.log

Comment: How this would help the OP?